# Creating a String matching DNA method

Tags: java, eclipse, pattern-matching, string-matching, dna-sequence

I am trying to create a method for a program where The bases in a DNAstrand object are compared to a smaller string of bases (this would be the parameter), and it would search for the pattern in the bases in the DNAstrand object. Once it finds the pattern, I want it to return the position number of the start of the pattern in the DNAStrand object. I have tried so far, but my code is not working. Here is my code so far (note I am using another method within another)

```
    for(int position =0; position + substrand.getLength() < (this.getLength()- substrand.getLength() +1); position ++){

        if(matchAt(substrand)){
            return position;
            } 
        } return -1; 
        } 










    protected boolean matchAt(DNAStrand substrand) { 

    for (int i = 0; i < (this.getLength()- substrand.getLength() +1); i++) { 
    if (this.getBaseAt(i) != substrand.getBaseAt(i)) {
        return false;
        } }return true; 
        }
```

Comment: Yeah you aren't really showing us much here. I do suggest since you are using Strings and matching perhaps look into Pattern class. You even included pattern matching in your tags and I see no reference to Pattern http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a substring within a string.

You can use String's .indexOf() function:

```
protected int matchAt(string substrand){
    return dnastrand.indexOf(substrand)
}
```

I don't know how the objects handle their toString() implementation specific to your classes, but that's the general idea. You don't need a for loop at all for this, and just return the int.

It returns the index of the first instance of the substring in the string.